# How to prove this in ring theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\Bbb{Z}_7$ be the ring of integers modulo $7$ and let $\Bbb{Z}[w]=\{a+bw:a,b \in \Bbb{Z}\}$ with $w^2+w+1=0$. Let $x=2-w$ show there exists $c \in \{0,1,2,...,6\}$ and $d\in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $a+bw+bx=c+7d$

I don't really know how to proceed in this. It looks to me like an application of the division theorem but I can't see what to do it on.

Comment: Would this work? $a+bw+bx=a+b(w+x)=a+2b=7d+c$ by the division theorem where $c,d$ have the required properties. I.e we divide $a+2b$ by $7$ then we have the quotient and remainder?

Comment: Unless you made a typo, this is just saying that you can divide $ a + 2b $ by $ 7 $ to get a quotient and a remainder, which is true since $ \mathbb{Z} $ is an Euclidean domain. Perhaps you mistyped the question?

Comment: No I don't think I mistyped the question it was just a lot easier than I thought.